# how to avoid getting same data on Jquery Scroll Down?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have following Jquery script Its uploads the mysql data on Scroll Down. The Problem is some times its request the same url and grab same data twice thrice. How I can avoid getting same data?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){ /* window on scroll run the function using jquery and ajax */
        var WindowHeight = $(window).height(); /* get the window height */
        if($(window).scrollTop() +1 >= $(document).height() - WindowHeight){ /* check is that user scrolls down to the bottom of the page */
            $("#loader").html("<img src='loading_icon.gif' alt='loading'/>"); /* displa the loading content */
            var LastDiv = $("#tabsul>li:last"); /* get the last div of the dynamic content using ":last" */
            var LastId  = $("#tabsul>li:last").attr("id"); /* get the id of the last div */
            var offset = $("#tabsul>li").length; //thats the size we have
            var ValueToPass = "Id="+ LastId;

            $.ajax({ /* post the values using AJAX */
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?= url('pages/ajax/All/')?>"+offset+"/",
                data: ValueToPass,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#loader").html("");
                    LastDiv.after(html);


                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question ,
It's a common problem since the AJAX is asynchronous

You can avoid the problem in two ways

**1 - Setting the `async` Parameter to false**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){ /* window on scroll run the function using jquery and ajax */
        var WindowHeight = $(window).height(); /* get the window height */
        if($(window).scrollTop() +1 >= $(document).height() - WindowHeight){ /* check is that user scrolls down to the bottom of the page */
            $("#loader").html("<img src='loading_icon.gif' alt='loading'/>"); /* displa the loading content */
            var LastDiv = $("#tabsul>li:last"); /* get the last div of the dynamic content using ":last" */
            var LastId  = $("#tabsul>li:last").attr("id"); /* get the id of the last div */
            var offset = $("#tabsul>li").length; //thats the size we have
            var ValueToPass = "Id="+ LastId;

            $.ajax({ /* post the values using AJAX */
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?= url('pages/ajax/All/')?>"+offset+"/",
                data: ValueToPass,
                cache: false,
                async:false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#loader").html("");
                    LastDiv.after(html);


                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**2 - Using boolean flags**

```
var flag = true; 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){ /* window on scroll run the function using jquery and ajax */
        var WindowHeight = $(window).height(); /* get the window height */
        if($(window).scrollTop() +1 >= $(document).height() - WindowHeight){ /* check is that user scrolls down to the bottom of the page */
            $("#loader").html("<img src='loading_icon.gif' alt='loading'/>"); /* displa the loading content */
            var LastDiv = $("#tabsul>li:last"); /* get the last div of the dynamic content using ":last" */
            var LastId  = $("#tabsul>li:last").attr("id"); /* get the id of the last div */
            var offset = $("#tabsul>li").length; //thats the size we have
            var ValueToPass = "Id="+ LastId;
            if(flag == true)
            {
               flag = false; 
            $.ajax({ /* post the values using AJAX */
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?= url('pages/ajax/All/')?>"+offset+"/",
                data: ValueToPass,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#loader").html("");
                    LastDiv.after(html);

                    flag = true; 
                }
            });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In this model you set a variable to be true when it's done from the previous request

Maybe you need to change the condition of the if statement if you want

I hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

Before the window scroll function add a variable outside of that scope.

```
var urlsLoaded = [];
$(window).scroll(function(){
```

Then after the following two lines, check if offset is in that array, if not, push it into the array and then perform the ajax.

```
var offset = $("#tabsul>li").length; //thats the size we have
var ValueToPass = "Id="+ LastId;

if(urlsLoaded.indexOf(offset)) == -1){
    urlsLoaded.push(offset);
    $.ajax({ /* post the values using AJAX */
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?= url('pages/ajax/All/')?>"+offset+"/",
        data: ValueToPass,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#loader").html("");
            LastDiv.after(html);
        }
    });
}else{
    //I'm guessing do nothing? if so, just remove the else
    //otherwise perform your logic here
}
```

JavaScript `.indexOf()` returns `-1` if the value does not exist in the area, so we directly compare to it.

I'd suggest caching etc normally, but if this is just for page specific logic so you don't show duplicate content, then this wlil work.

**Edit**

Changed out `$.inArray()` in favor of `.indexOf()`